# Are these determiners or are there omissions?

Tags: determiners

> From the moment they arrived, the Twins had been admonishing Eve for having her baby at home. They told her she was endangering her baby’s welfare and that in these modern times, it was irresponsible to give birth anywhere but in the most **prestigious** of all hospitals with the most **expensive** of all doctors. Eve tried to explain to them that
>
> (Garth Stein, The Art of Racing in the Rain)

Are there *one* that is omitted after *prestigious* and *expensive*, or are these *the most prestigious of* and *the most expensive of* determiners for next noun phrases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s nothing missing.

In the European languages I know, adjectives may act as nouns—in fact, grammarians classified adjectives and nouns in the same category until the 18th century. This is true to a limited extent in English, too, although English is not happy using an adjective as a noun unless it designates a category as well as a quality:

> We’ve got red hats and blue hats—which do you want?
>   I’ll take a red.

Superlatives however may always be treated as nouns, and that is what is happening here. *Most expensive* is a superlative, and *The most expensive of all hospitals/doctors* are noun phrases.